# How to sum a column in python without calling it a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, aggregation

I have data that outputs into a csv file as:

```
url  date          id    hits
a    2017-01-01    123     2
a    2017-01-01    123     2
b    2017-01-01    45      25
c    2017-01-01    123     5
d    2017-01-03    678     1
d    2017-01-03    678     7
```

and so on where hits is the number of times the id value appears on a given day per url. (ie: the id number 123 appears 2 times on 2017-01-01 for url "a".

I need to create another column after hits, called "total hits" that captures the total number of hits there are per day for a given url, date and id value. So the output would look like this..

```
url  date          id    hits   total_hits
a    2017-01-01    123     2         4
a    2017-01-01    123     2         4
b    2017-01-01    45      25        25
c    2017-01-01    123     5         5
d    2017-01-03    678     1         8
d    2017-01-03    678     7         8
```

if there are solutions to this without using pandas or numpy that would be amazing.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll ask the x-y question: how is it that this data *cannot* be converted to a data frame or array?  Your terminology is inconsistent, so I need to check.  You already have the data in memory in *some* form; it's unclear what you have or why you have these restrictions.

Comment: "2017-01-01    123" happens 3 times 2+2+5 so total should be 9 not 4 and 5.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's dependent on the url column as well though

Comment: you can use aggregating `grp = list(df.columns)[:3];df.drop("hits",1).set_index(grp).join(df.groupby(grp).agg(sum)).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple with standard python installation.

- read & parse file using line-by-line read & split
- create a `collections.defaultdict(int)` to count the occurences of the url/date/id triplet
- add the info in an extra column
- write back (I chose csv)

like this:

```
import collections,csv

d = collections.defaultdict(int)

rows = []

with open("input.csv") as f:
    title = next(f).split()  # skip title
    for line in f:
        toks = line.split()
        d[toks[0],toks[1],toks[2]] += int(toks[3])
        rows.append(toks)

# complete data
for row in rows:
    row.append(d[row[0],row[1],row[2]])
title.append("total_hits")


with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerow(title)
    cw.writerows(rows)
```

here's the output file:

```
url,date,id,hits,total_hits
a,2017-01-01,123,2,4
a,2017-01-01,123,2,4
b,2017-01-01,45,25,25
c,2017-01-01,123,5,5
d,2017-01-03,678,1,8
d,2017-01-03,678,7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

# Open the input and output CSV files
with open('input.csv', 'r') as input_file, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    # Create CSV reader and writer objects
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames + ['total_hits'])

    # Write the header to the output file
    writer.writeheader()

    # Initialize a dictionary to store the total hits per day for each url, date, and id
    total_hits_per_day = {}

    # Iterate over each row in the input CSV file
    for row in reader:
        # Extract the url, date, id, and hits values from the current row
        url = row['url']
        date = row['date']
        id_value = row['id']
        hits = int(row['hits'])

        # Calculate the total hits per day for the current url, date, and id
        key = (url, date, id_value)
        total_hits_per_day[key] = total_hits_per_day.get(key, 0) + hits

        # Update the current row with the total_hits value
        row['total_hits'] = total_hits_per_day[key]

        # Write the updated row to the output CSV file
        writer.writerow(row)
```